# Как разбить текст на строки?

Tags: c#

Как из

```
string d = "q1 \n q2 \n q3"
```

получить

```
string[] f = "q1","q2","q3"
```

?

P.S. Знаю, что нужно использовать `d.Split`, но не знаю как.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, поставив где надо кавычки и т. п.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
f = d.Split('\n');
```

Или даже так, если у вас в строке есть лишние начальные или конечные пробелы

```
f = d.Split('\n').Select(x=>x.Trim(' ')).ToArray();
```

Кроме того ваш код работать не будет, так как у вас отсутствуют кавычки в задании строк. Вам необходимо начать с изучения основ, базы C#.

Comment: Кавычки я в вопросе забыл поставить, так то я знаю про них конечно)